# In GCp Cloud SQL instance do I have access to the my.cnf file

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I need to do some manual configurations in CloudSQL Instance. The question is that do I have access to the my.cnf file in GCP DB instance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to the raw configuration file but you can configure certain flags in the UI or using gcloud.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags